# Relative change with matrix operators

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is it possible to define the operator $P$ to get the following for an input matrix with all elements $a,b,c,d,e,f$ positive:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f \\
\end{bmatrix} Q P 
=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 \\
0&-1
\end{bmatrix} P=\begin{bmatrix}
a-b & b- c\\
d -e & e- f \\
\end{bmatrix}P = \left[
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}-
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{b}{a} & \frac{c}{d}\\
\frac{e}{d} & \frac{f}{e} \\
\end{bmatrix}\right]P$$  Actually this is the [relative change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference) with matrix operators.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not even linear in $a$.

Comment: What do you do if $a, d$ or $e$ is $0$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks the interest. All elements are positive.

Comment: Sorry I have made a refactoring in my post hopping to be more clear.

Comment: Taking a limit as all variables $ \to 0+$, $b/a$, $c/d$ and $f/e$ could go to anything.  So your $P$ must be $0$.